# Pythagorean triplet mutiple angles

Tags: complex-numbers, rational-numbers, angle, pythagorean-triples

If both cos and sin are rational, then, is sin(nx) rational?

From just checking for obvious values other than, 0,1
For tan(x)=3/4,  for n=2, we get another pythagorean triplet of 24,7,25, for n=3, 336,527,625, for n=4, 354144,164833,390625..

If this trend continuous, is there a De moivre proof? I would like to stay away from number theory if possible.

Comment: Induction. It is convenient to prove the "stronger" result that $\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$ are **both** rational.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\mathbb Q[i]$ (the set of complex numbers with rational real and imaginary parts) is closed under multiplication, it follows directly from [de Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula) that if $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ are both rational, then so are $\cos(nx)$ and $\sin(nx)$ for all integer $n$.

Comment: The point was how is it closed? I think I'm missing something major here..

Comment: @ELiT: $(a+bi)(c+di)=(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i$, and if $a,b,c,d$ are all rational, then $ac-bd$ and $ad+bc$ are also rational.

Comment: And I'm sitting with egg on my face.. Thanks guys.. Awesome community